# Android threads and services

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I have this service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    running = true;
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            while (running) { Thread.sleep(60); ... }
        }
    }.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

I saw this example on the Android Bootcamp course on youtube and it worked.
My question is: is that not a dangerous thing to do? because if the service will be stopped while the thread is sleeping its memory could be evicted by the GC and then the thread will try and access an unallocated variable(running)... I suspect it works because it adds + 1 to running's reference counter and that why it will only be evicted when the thread will be over but I would love for someone to confirm this and maybe give a detailed explanation of the process.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the service will be stopped while the thread is sleeping its memory could be evicted by the GC

This assumption is wrong.

May I suggest you [this reading](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx) about Java GC. Here is a relevant quote:

> Active Java threads are always considered live objects and are therefore GC roots.

So your thread is sleeping, but it is still in a running state. The fact that it is sleeping is not important here. What is important is that the thread is not finished yet (as you said in your question).

Thread is not finished, means that it is still active and so the thread is a GC-root.

Since it holds a reference to the member `running` : the service won't be garbage collected.

Is it dangerous ? Yes ! because it is a potential memory leak, not because there is a risk to access to a unallocated variable.

---

To avoid memory leak you must ensure that at some point : your thread will finish (i.e. `running` became false)... for every possible situation :

- normal execution of the service (of course)
- unexpected exception
- service killed by the OS

Comment: This is the correct answer. Even if set running=false in onDestroy(), we still have a potential memory leak if we don't ensure the thread is finished before onDestroy() exits. This is why we don't use naked Thread's and instead use the higher level constructs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! what are these higher level constructs? and how would you do this without the risk for a memory leak? (I want the service to run and do something every 60 seconds until the service is stopped).
Other then defining the thread in the service class and stopping it on onDestroy of the service.

Comment: You could use the ExecutorService returned from Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() for this. Then you can use shutdown() and awaitTermination() to make sure it shuts down properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a running thread (it does not really sleep), it holds reference to the service. Which means service and everything service has access to will not be collected and released.

Comment: What do you mean it doesnt really sleep? and how does the thread's  status influences its ability to have or not have references to objects in memory?

Comment: while (running) { Thread.sleep(60); ... } it does not sleep, it is in a loop forever, based on your code. Thread is running, it is executable piece of code, which holds references and preventing garbage collection.

Comment: It does sleep, for 60 seconds because of `Thread.sleep(60);`.
Those references are exactly what im asking about, so basically at compile time the jvm checks what variables are referenced inside of the thread and these variables has a "reference count" of 2? (from the service and from the thread)

Comment: I am sorry I am little lost. What do you exactly ask?

Answer (score 0):

What you posted won't compile without declaring `running` final. When you declare the variable final, the new instance of `Thread` captures the value and the value will remain as is regardless of what happens on the outside.

There generally isn't such thing as accessing an unallocated variable in Java.

Comment: Actually it would: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9dk82ux-fA&list=PLE08A97D36D5A255F#t=1311

Comment: That's not what you posted. Can you edit your post to reflect the code you are asking about.

Comment: And in regards to the code you are asking about, the reference to the instance variable of the Service in the running thread will prevent the Service from being GC'd.

Comment: Yes, I remembered incorrectly, can you explain what does it do when the variable doesnt have a type? it defines it as a constant in the static variables area of the memory?

Comment: 'running' is declared as an instance variable of the Service there, I'm sure.

Comment: I edited my post, also can you explain what does it do when the variable doesnt have a type? it defines it as a constant in the static variables area of the memory?